# VBA Help - Loop copy/paste/pdf export

Tags: excel, vba, loops, dashboard

I have a dashboard report (worksheet "Report") that populates via entry of a identifier # in a specific cell (Cell B5).

The source data for the dashboard report (and the identifier that changes the information presented in the dashboard) is in a separate worksheet titled "Data".  I would like to do the following, but have been unable to develop code that accomplishes the end task (I'm brand new to VBA).

1. Filter, by a specific location that's listed in the data set, to one site in the "Data" worksheet (i.e. I don't want to export dashboards for all locations at one time). For example, the desired site would be "Atlanta", with 5 other locations included across the population of the data that would be excluded.
2. Automatically copy/paste each identifying # for any record under "Atlanta" to Cell B5 in the "Report" worksheet
3. Export that dashboard in the "report" worksheet to pdf with a cell(B6, which is a person's name, from the "report" worksheet) in the pdf's filename.
4. Continue looping through the filtered data set to export a dashboard for each person in that specific set of data (the number of rows would vary across each data set filtered by location)

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

I developed this; however, it requires that I extract out the market specific list into a separate worksheet and lists the id # instead of name in the pdf filename.

```vb
Sub providerreportexport()

' Provider Report Export Macro

    Dim datasheet As Worksheet 'where is the data copied from
    Dim reportsheet As Worksheet 'where is the data pasted to and printed from as pdf
    Dim finalrow As Long
    Dim i As Integer 'row counter

    'set variables
    Set datasheet = Sheet6
    Set reportsheet = Sheet4
    finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'goto datasheet
    datasheet.Select
    Range("B2").Select
    finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'loop through the rows to find the matching records

    For i = 1 To finalrow

        If Cells(i, 1) = "" Then 'if the name in column A matches the search name then copy
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5)).Copy 'copy column listing ID
            reportsheet.Select 'go to the report sheet
            Range("B5").Select.Paste 'paste id into report
        End If

'Export each as pdf

     ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
             Filename:="C:\documents\new folder\Productivity Report", _
             Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
             IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
             OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post what code you have and clarify the problem(s) with it?

Comment: On the data sheet, is Atlanta a column heading with a list of numbers below it? Are the other locations in similar columns.

Comment: The locations (including Altlanta and the other locations) have their own column, with the respective location listed for that row.   Each identifying # is listed in a row, with multiple columns that include name, location, and other data pertaining to that individual.